# How do I create a tabbed control in a Python FMX GUI App?

Tags: python, user-interface, tabs, firemonkey

I'm making a Python FMX GUI App and I basically want three tabs on it like this:
[image: Delphi App with tabs]

I tried doing this:

```
self.TabControl1 = TabControl(self)
self.TabControl1.Parent = self
self.TabControl1.Align = "Client"
self.TabControl1.Margins.Top = 50
self.TabControl1.Margins.Bottom = 50
self.TabControl1.Margins.Left = 50
self.TabControl1.Margins.Right = 50

self.TabControl1.Tabs.Add("Tab1")
self.TabControl1.Tabs.Add("Tab2")
self.TabControl1.Tabs.Add("Tab3")
```

The `self.TabControl1.Tabs.Add()` fails and errors with `AttributeError: Error in getting property "Tabs". Error: Unknown attribute`.

What is the correct way to give tabs to the `TabControl` component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code to create a tab:

```
self.TabItem1 = TabItem(self.TabControl1)
self.TabItem1.Text = "tab 1"
self.TabItem1.Parent = self.TabControl1
```

Here's the full code to create 3 tabs on a `Form` similar to the one you posted:

```
from delphifmx import *

class frmMain(Form):
    def __init__(self, owner):
        self.Caption = 'My Application with three tabs'
        self.Width = 1000
        self.Height = 500

        self.TabControl1 = TabControl(self)
        self.TabControl1.Parent = self
        self.TabControl1.Align = "Client"
        self.TabControl1.Margins.Top = 50
        self.TabControl1.Margins.Bottom = 50
        self.TabControl1.Margins.Left = 50
        self.TabControl1.Margins.Right = 50

        self.TabItem1 = TabItem(self.TabControl1)
        self.TabItem1.Text = "Your first tab"
        self.TabItem1.Parent = self.TabControl1

        self.TabItem2 = TabItem(self.TabControl1)
        self.TabItem2.Text = "Your second tab"
        self.TabItem2.Parent = self.TabControl1

        self.TabItem3 = TabItem(self.TabControl1)
        self.TabItem3.Text = "Your third tab"
        self.TabItem3.Parent = self.TabControl1


def main():
    Application.Initialize()
    Application.Title = "My Application"
    Application.MainForm = frmMain(Application)
    Application.MainForm.Show()
    Application.Run()
    Application.MainForm.Destroy()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image: Python GUI App with tabs]